# Encryption of files with CryptoJs and decryption in Python (AES CBC)

Tags: javascript, python, encryption, cryptography, cryptojs

I'm trying to encrypt files (trying with png) in Javascript (ReactJs) and I want to be able to decrypt the files and restore their original state in Python.

I've tried multiple approaches but the below JS code was the only one I got working properly. With the JS code, I'm able to get back the png in its original form. However, I seem to be missing something with padding as I keep getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "***/encrypt_decrypt_using_aes.py", line 110, in <module>
    decrypted = decrypt(encData, key, iv)
  File "***/encrypt_decrypt_using_aes.py", line 103, in decrypt
    return unpad(cipher.decrypt(enc),16)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/Crypto/Util/Padding.py", line 90, in unpad
    raise ValueError("Padding is incorrect.")
ValueError: Padding is incorrect.
```

I tried playing with ZeroPadding, NoPadding, PKCS7 but nothing worked.

Any ideas on what I am missing?

**JS code:**

```
    function decrypt(input) {
      var file = input;
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = () => {
          var key = "1234567887654321";  
    
          var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(reader.result, key, {mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC});               // Decryption: I: Base64 encoded string (OpenSSL-format) -> O: WordArray
          var typedArray = convertWordArrayToUint8Array(decrypted);               // Convert: WordArray -> typed array
    
          var fileDec = new Blob([typedArray]);                                   // Create blob from typed array
    
          var a = document.createElement("a");
          var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(fileDec);
          var filename = file.name.substr(0, file.name.length - 4);
          a.href = url;
          a.download = filename;
          a.click();
          window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
      };
      reader.readAsText(file);
    }

    function encrypt(input) {
      var file = input
      console.log("In Encrypt")
      console.log(file)
      var reader = new FileReader();
      var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('53509bee-8207-11');
      reader.onload = () => {
          var key = "1234567887654321";
          var wordArray = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(reader.result);           // Convert: ArrayBuffer -> WordArray
          var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(wordArray, key, {iv: iv, mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC}).toString();        // Encryption: I: WordArray -> O: -> Base64 encoded string (OpenSSL-format)
  
          var fileEnc = new Blob([encrypted]);                                    // Create blob from string
  
          // var a = document.createElement("a");
          // var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(fileEnc);
          var filename = input.name + ".enc";
          console.log(filename)
          var file = new File([fileEnc], filename);
          // a.href = url;
          // a.download = filename;
          // a.click();
          // window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
          setFiles2State(files2State => ({
            fileList2: [...files2State.fileList2, file],
          }));
          console.log("OUT LIST")
          console.log(files2State)
      };


      reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

  }
```

**Python code (Not working):**

```
import base64 
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Util.Padding import pad,unpad

def encrypt(data,key,iv):
        data= pad(data.encode(),16)
        cipher = AES.new(key.encode('utf-8'),AES.MODE_CBC,iv)
        return base64.b64encode(cipher.encrypt(data))

def decrypt(enc,key,iv=None):
        enc = base64.b64decode(enc)
        # enc = enc.encode('utf-8')
        if iv == None:
            cipher = AES.new(key.encode('utf-8'), AES.MODE_CBC)
        else:
            cipher = AES.new(key.encode('utf-8'), AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
        return unpad(cipher.decrypt(enc),16)


with open("demo_file.png.enc", "r+") as fileIn:
    encData = fileIn.read()
    key = "1234567887654321"
    iv = "53509bee-8207-11".encode('utf-8')
    decrypted = decrypt(encData, key, iv)
    

with open("demo_file.png", "wb") as fileOut:
    fileOut.write(decrypted)
```

Comment: The CryptoJS part, unlike the Python code, uses a key derivation and generates a ciphertext in OpenSSL format. Therefore, both codes are incompatible. To avoid the built-in key derivation on the CryptoJS side, the key must be passed as a `WordArray` (see the CryptoJS documentation, section [_The Cipher Input_](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#the-cipher-input)), e.g. : `var key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("1234567887654321")`.

Comment: Indeed that was it. Passing the key as mentioned does the trick. Thanks a lot!